# MVC 4 Modularization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mef

I'm trying to create a modularization mechanism for an MVC 4 site.  I have most things working via a custom ViewEngine (Razor based) but after FindView returns I get an error that the model listed in a view cannot be resolved.

The model and controller are in the module's DLL and this DLL is loaded in a MEF container.  The controller is executing ok but something is clearly missing when it comes to resolving the @model in the view.

Anyone got any ideas what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I was copying the module dll's to bin\modules so the compilation of the .cshtml.cs file couldn't find the referenced model.  I now just copy the dlls to the bin folder and it works just fine.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Every namespace that needs to be resolved in the View must be declared in the web.config in the views folder. Have you done that?

Another way is to specify it with full namespace in the View.

Comment: Ah, good point, thanks.  No I didnt have this but adding it doesnt help much.  At least now I can see that its looking in the correct namespace, but it still cant find it.

Comment: It's a compilation error from the index.cshtml.cs file that is generated.  I've figured it out tho, sort of, see below.